# Remove \par from string

Tags: macros, strings

I have to put a string in various places of a book. This string is stored in a macro

```
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
\newcommand{\thesubtitle}{#1}
}

\subtitle{The quite long \par subtitle}
```

Long subtitles should be splited in the cover using `\par`. But in other places the subtitle should be in one line.
Is there a way to remove this `\par` or equivalent `\\` from the input string to store in another macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A definition such as

```
{\def\par{\unskip\space\ignorespaces}\thesubtitle}
```

should work. This doesn't of course remove the `\par` token, but that is not required for the stated aim of making the text a single paragraph.

Comment: It is working indeed, either for `\par` and for `\\`. I will wait a bit if someone finds a more elegant solution, before accepting :-)

Comment: "more elegant" how could it be possible to be more elegant than one of my answers? :-)

Comment: it seems there is no a "more elegant" way ;-)